# How to return Computed value in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sendmail

Hi I have field RefernceNo. where it is computer generated and after saving record the user will receive email in that referenceNo is missing can anyone please help me how to return value before sending email below is the code for save button and send email code.

Comment: "return value before sending email" return value *from*? "before sending email" do you mean before `smtp.Send()`?

Comment: Hi yes I have to return the referenceNo before sending email so that I can get in email with reference N.

Comment: In your stored procedure you want to retrieve the value after you save it and return it as out parameter You can use the scope_identity() function to return the latest primary key from the table you just inserted into.

Comment: How to add that scope_identity to get the value

Comment: Show your code - you will get much more help, now it just guessing and assuming